# how to make a BuiltList<Post> out of List<RecordSnapshot> in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am trying to use sembast with built value While trying to make a BuiltList out of List I got Stuck

> The named parameter 'posts' isn't defined.
>   Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'posts'.dart(undefined_named_parameter).

and also

> The method 'fromMap' isn't defined for the class 'Post'.
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromMap'.

```
Future<PostsList> getPostsFromDb() async {
    print('Loading from database');

    // post list
    var postsList;

    // fetching data
    final recordSnapshots = await _postsStore.find(
      await _db,
    );

    // Making a List<Post> out of List<RecordSnapshot>
    if (recordSnapshots.length > 0) {
      postsList = PostsList(
          posts: recordSnapshots.map((snapshot) {
        final post = Post.fromMap(snapshot.value);
        // An ID is a key of a record from the database.
        post.id = snapshot.key;
        return post;
      }).toList());
    }

    return postsList;
  }
```

**PostList Class**

```
abstract class PostsList implements Built<PostsList, PostsListBuilder> {
  PostsList._();

  factory PostsList([updates(PostsListBuilder b)]) = _$PostsList;


  BuiltList<Post> get posts;

  String toJson() {
    return json.encode(serializers.serializeWith(PostsList.serializer, this));
  }

  static PostsList fromJson(String jsonString) {
    return serializers.deserializeWith(
        PostsList.serializer, json.decode(jsonString));
  }

  static Serializer<PostsList> get serializer => _$postsListSerializer;
}
```

got Stuck Please help

Comment: Hi Anbu, good start. Can you paste the code here instead of an image? Might be helpful for us to help you better. Curious what's the implementation of the `fromMap`?

Comment: @JoshuadeGuzman Please Find that I have edited the question above and find the ```frommap ``` implementation below

```factory Post.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Post(
         userId: json["userId"],
         id: json["id"],
         title: json["title"],
        body: json["body"],
       );
```
Now I have Changed as below

```static Post fromJson(String jsonString) {
    return serializers.deserializeWith(
        Post.serializer, json.decode(jsonString));
  }```

Comment: try to include `PostsList` too in your code because  `posts` might not exist there.

Comment: Based on the error message above, it seems like `PostsList` doesn't not have a `posts` parameter. Do you mind sharing a snippet of your `PostsList` constructor? Also, I need to see your `Post.fromMap()` method.

Comment: @JoshuadeGuzman,Please Find the Questions updated and  I changed the model class with builtvalue lib earlier it was like as I mentioned in earlier comment

Comment: Do you mind sharing what exact SDK or library did you use to serialize your payload in the `PostsList`?

Comment: @JoshuadeGuzman 
```built_collection: ^4.2.2
built_value: ^6.7.1```

Comment: Can you try populating the `PostsList` without using a named argument `posts`? Eg. `PostsList([<array value here>])`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PostsList` class does not actually contain a field `posts`. It's a getter, therefore you cannot set its value, and there is no constructor in `PostsList` that accepts a `posts` parameter. Therefore, it is exactly what the error message tells you: `posts` parameter is not defined for any constructor.

For your second issue, it seems that you either don't have a factory constructor named `Post.fromMap(args)` or that you're not passing the right data type to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am Little bit confused in converting below Func
```final recordSnap = await _postsStore.find(
      await _db,
      finder: finder,
    );

    // Making a List<Post> out of List<RecordSnapshot>
    return recordSnap.map((snapshot) {
      final post = Post.fromJson(snapshot.value);
      // An ID is a key of a record from the database.
      post.id = snapshot.key;
      return post;
    }).toList();```
frmJson
```static Post fromJson(String jsonString) {
    return serializers.deserializeWith(
        Post.serializer, json.decode(jsonString));
  }```

Comment: Can you please help me in converting 
the argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Comment: This seems to be a serialization issue, so I would look at what your serializers are doing. That error message tells you that you're trying to pass a Map to something that expects a String - I would assume it's that last part where you're trying to use `deserializeWith` since that's where I would expect the serializer to not need you to first convert to a Map from JSON

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @all for your replies, I have Fixed the issue as changing below

```
final List<Post> postResponse = deserializeListOf<Post>(res).asList();

final Serializers serializers = _$serializers;
Serializers standardSerializers = (serializers.toBuilder()..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin())).build();

T deserialize<T>(dynamic value) =>
    standardSerializers.deserializeWith<T>(standardSerializers.serializerForType(T), value);

BuiltList<T> deserializeListOf<T>(dynamic value) =>
    BuiltList.from(value.map((value) => deserialize<T>(value)).toList(growable: false));
```

It works fine